# The most Efficient Algorithm for Factoring Polynomial Over Finite Field

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, finite-groups, factoring

I have a polynomial defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number (e.g. 256-bit).

The polynomail's degree is big (e.g. at least $10^5$).

*My Goal is:* To find the roots of the polynomial.

One way to do that is to factorize the polynomial then find the low degree polynomials'roots. My polynomial can be constructed to be a monic polynomial (if this helps to speed up the proceess). Here, how fast I can find the roots matters to me.

**Question**: What is the most efficient algorithm that factorize the polynomial over a finite field.

I am aware of this paper: http://www.shoup.net/papers/lille.pdf
but I want something faster e.g. $O(n)$

Comment: Are you looking for a theoretical result to get to O(n) complexity, or do you have a concrete problem you want to solve? Do you just care about the roots, or also about other factors?

Comment: @ahulpke I only care about the roots. However, I want to recove the roots in $O(n)$ if it's possible.

Comment: If you only care about $n$ and not about $p$, you could try all field elements.

Comment: @ahulpke No, it's impossible. Please note that $p$ is very large, 256-bit, so I cannot enumerate the field elements.

Comment: Of course it is impossible in practice, but your question was on complexity depending on $n$. So you also want complexity depending on $p$. Is linear dependence on $n$ plausible? What would be the cost of testing for roots?

Comment: @ahulpke So the factorization is a suitable option: we first factorize the polynomial into low degree polynomials and then find the polynomials root. Now the question is: What is the most efficient factorization algorithm? Can we do any better than $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning the complexity of factorizations, I believe the best current result is

Kedlaya, Umans:
Fast polynomial factorization and modular composition.
SIAM J. Comput. 40 (2011), no. 6, 1767–1802.

which gives complexity of roughly $(n^{1.5}+n\log q)\log q$ for a field with $q$ elements.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the gcd(x^q-x,f) trick, but had trouble computing x^q :P Reducing x^p mod f, and then composing up to q worked. By the way, the paper is online for free: https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/71792

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice probabilistic algorithm to find the roots of a polynomial mod $p$ that might suit you, though I'm not sure of it's complexity. It is described in Cohen's [A course in computational number theory](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Course-Computational-Algebraic-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/3540556400) pages 36-38. If $G(X)$ is your polynomial then first compute
    $$ F(X) = \operatorname{gcd}(X^p-X,G(X)) $$
Now $F(X)$ has only linear factors and now 
the key idea es to use a series of random $a\pmod p$ and find the gcd of $F(X)$ and  $(X-a)^{\frac{p-1}2}-1$, modulo $p$. Suppose you get
   $$ A(X) = \operatorname{gcd} ((X-a)^{\frac{p-1}2}-1,F(X)) $$
Then $A(X)$ is a factor of $F(X)$ if it is not trivial, you can repeat the algorithm with $F(X)/A(X)$ and $A(X)$ until you get linear or quadratic factors that you can solve directly.

As $(X-a)^{\frac{p-1}2}-1$ is a very large polynomial you have first to compute 
 $$ (X-a)^{\frac{p-1}2} \pmod{p,F(X)} $$
using the power algorithm and working modulo $p$ and modulo $F(X)$. And the same for $X^p-X$.

It works because the factors of $(X-a)^{\frac{p-1}2}-1 \pmod p$ are all the integers $u$ such that $u-a$ is a quadratic residue, and this splits "randomly" the integers mod $p$ in two halves, and the gcd picks the factors in each set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure if it works well for a very large field. In my case $p$ is a 256-bit number.

Comment: Why not? All the residues will be 256-bit numbers and all the polynomials will have less than $n$ terms, with $n$ the degree of $F$. I'm not sure if you can hope for anything faster.